# How to fetch all the direct messages using Twython?

Tags: twitter, twython

I am trying to fetch all the direct messages in my account. But I tried to use cursor for fetching. But I'm getting an error like

```
TypeError: cursor() missing 1 required positional argument: 'function'
```

My code is below.

```
from twython import Twython

APP_KEY = 'KEY'
APP_SECRET = 'SECRET'
ACCESS_TOKEN = 'TOKEN'
ACCESS_SECRET = 'SECRET'

twitter = Twython(APP_KEY,APP_SECRET,ACCESS_TOKEN,ACCESS_SECRET)

for tweet in Twython.cursor(twitter.get_direct_messages(),since_id=1,count=100):
print (tweet)
```

Please help on this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Pretty sure that you need to invoke the `.cursor` method on the `twitter` object, not on the `Twython` class.

So try

```
for tweet in twitter.cursor(twitter.get_direct_messages(),since_id=1,count=100):
    print (tweet)
```

Specifically, this works for me:

```
results = twitter.cursor(twitter.get_direct_messages,count=2)
for result in results:
     print result['text']
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also access them directly from the return of get_direct_messages:

```
messages = twitter.get_direct_messages(count=200)

for message_id in messages:
    id = message_id['id']
    text = message_id['text']
    print text
```