# How to "like" Direct Messages using the Twython Python library?

Tags: python, api, twitter, twython

Using the Twython Python library, I discovered that I can send Direct Messages (DM) leveraging the following code:

```
api.send_direct_message(event={'type':'message_create','message_create':{'target':{'recipient_id':RECIPIENT_ID},'message_data':{'text':DM_TEXT}}})
```

From [How to fetch all the direct messages using Twython?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38549338/how-to-fetch-all-the-direct-messages-using-twython), I learned how to get all the DM sent to me.
In fact, what I want now is to "like" those fetched DM.

Is it possible to do it with the Twython library ? And if yes, how ?

Answer (score 1):

At the time of writing, the Twitter API does not provide a feature for adding reactions to Direct Messages, so this is not possible.